# $.each and $.getJSON methods to array of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

After converting a array of names in a array of url links for users online and offline and only names for closed accounts `["https://link_1","https://link_2",name(for closed account),"https//link_3",...]` through the $.map method and the .getJSON within that.

I try to apply the $.each method with a condition within again, so if the element starts by "http" I applied .getJSON method to work with the JSON object of the element (link) and add up to my html the values of their properties( e.g. html+=json.name); if the element doesn't start by "http" add up the value of the element only (e.g. html+=value). It doesn't work; the html variable takes index and value within jQuery.each, but not the json object of the nested .getJSON method. Where I lost?

```
 channels=["https://link1","https://link2","name(for closed account)",....];
var html="";
 $.each(channels,function(index,value){

    // for elements that are links
    if(value.substring(0,4)=="http"){

        $.getJSON(value,function(json){
          html+=json.name;
      });
    }
       // for elements that are not links
    else {
      html+= value;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Best guess is you are trying to use `html` before ajax is done. Important to realize that ajax is asynchrnous. Really not clear what specific problem is though...inside the `each` or using the data

Comment: Just cannot find what the problem is! I think your code can run properly,except the sequence of the value of 'html'

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON requests will return asynchronously, so if you test the value of `html` right below the code you provided, none of those JSON requests will have returned, so the corresponding response data will be missing in `html`.

Instead, you need to use the callback function of the JSON request to keep track of how many replies you have received, and when you have all of them, only then do something with `html`.

Here is some suggested code:

```
function buildHtml(channels, ready) {
    // Use an array, so you can store each response in the corresponding slot
    var html = [];
    // Keep a count of the replies you still need
    var count = channels.length;
    $.each(channels,function(index, value){
        // for elements that are links
        if(value.substring(0,4)=="http"){
            $.getJSON(value,function(json){
                html[index] = json.name;
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    // All is done, notify the caller:
                    if (ready) ready(html.join(''));
                }
          });
        }
           // for elements that are not links
        else {
            html[index] = value;
            count--;
        }
    });
    if (count == 0) { // Only true if there were no http entries:
        // All is done, notify the caller:
        if (ready) ready(html.join(''));
    }
}

channels=["https://link1","https://link2","name(for closed account)",....];
// Provide a call back function that is called when html is complete:
buildHtml(channels, function (html) {
    console.log('The returned HTML is: ' + html);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it fully works. Many thanks. What I can't see is why we need a condition for count==0 within the .getJSON code if we put the same condition in the outer pat of the code just below the variable count. In general I would need some more enlightenment about javascript asynchronous. Someone knows some resource highlighting this point.

Comment: The condition is needed at both places. It is necessary at the end of the function to cover the case where you don't do any JSON calls at all. So to make sure the `ready` callback is called in that case, it must be added at the end of the function. In the JSON callbacks it is necessary for all cases where you have at least one "http" entry, since for those you will only have the value at a later time (asynchronous) and only then you can check whether you have an answer to every array element.